# JSP formatDate yielding Full Dates when in email

Tags: java, jsp, date, taglib, formatdatetime

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/jstl-core.tld" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/jstl-fmt.tld" prefix="fmt"%>
<c:set var="now" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />

<p>
   <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="MMMM dd" />,<br/>
   <fmt:formatDate value="${now}" pattern="yyyy" />
</p>
```

When I view this code as is, in a browser, it displays as it should

```
Full Month Day,
Four-Digit Year
```

This is just the base jsp, a collegue of mine is using this base, and having an action use it to populate an email. When you view the email, in whatever client you use, you see:

```
Month Day Four-Digit Year [Hour:Minute:Second Time Zone],
Month Day Four-Digit Year [Hour:Minute:Second Time Zone]
```

I, at one point, had a `type="date"` tag in my `fmt:formatDate`, but it made no difference

Comment: Can you show us his code?

Comment: @alfreema Or her code.

Comment: RESOLVED: The JSTL was not parsing the fmt tags properly, so we just wrote a scriptlet.